# What is the advantage of implementing NSMutableArray as a 2-3 tree?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, data-structures, tree, nsmutablearray

I read elsewhere that `NSMutableArray` is implemented several different ways, depending on size, and is sometimes implemented as a [2-3 tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933_tree) instead of just an array in memory. The implication is that doing things like removing an object is not as expensive as having to copy the entire tail end of the array over by one.

I was wondering if there was a quick summary of the implementation, so that I don't have to dig through the source code.

1. How is the array ordered?
2. Is the root node the middle of the array?
3. How does the array find the nth element?
4. Are there other advantages
   to implementing the array as a 2-3 tree other than fast removal of
   objects near the front of the array?

Searching the interwebs, I couldn't find anything that discussed implementing a mutable array as a tree.

**Edit: Short Answer:** it appears that NSMutableArray is implemented as a circular buffer, so the question makes no sense. If there is an advantage to implementing an array as a 2-3 tree, I would still like to know it.

Comment: Here is an article that kind of talks around it: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html

Comment: Implementation details are implementation details.  If you can dig through Foundation and find the particular class implementing them as 2-3 trees, then you could just disassemble it and learn more.  But for all we know, it has been removed or revised.

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't trying to pin down the internal implementation of NSMutableArray, which I trust to just work, instead I was actually wondering why there would be any advantage to implementing an array as a 2-3 tree (in NSMutableArray or any other array in any language). In other words, I read that it was implemented that way, and then asked myself "why would they?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bartosz Ciechanowski has your answer in incredible detail at his blog post ["Exposing NSMutableArray"](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/03/05/exposing-nsmutablearray/)

tl;dr: It's a "circular buffer:"

> Data Structure
>
> As you might have guessed, __NSArrayM makes use of circular buffer. This data structure is extremely simple, but a little bit more sophisticated than regular array/buffer. The contents of circular buffer can wrap around when either end is reached.
>
> Circular buffer has some very cool properties. Notably, unless the buffer is full, insertion/deletion from either end doesn’t require any memory to be moved. Let’s analyze how the class utilizes circular buffer to be superior in its behavior in comparison to C array.

Historically, __NSArrayM is a newer-than-Cocoa class name-- it wasn't called that in OSX 10.0, but I can't find a good link for the older names.  Maybe it used to be a tree.  The [link](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html) in your first comment makes it sound like in 2005, at large sizes it was not a circular buffer internally.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent resource. So it turns out that CFArray and NSMutable array are not built up from a tree after all, although maybe they were in the past. So perhaps my question of why someone would ever use a 2-3 tree implementation for an array is a pointless question.

Comment: Turns out this was [covered here before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591296/what-is-the-data-structure-behind-nsmutablearray) -- but I still can't find much detail on the switch to `__NSArrayM` from whatever came before.  Insertion in the middle is always linear now?  Was it always so?  Or did it used to implement a tree at large sizes for quicker insertion?