# NSArray alloc and init

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm a little confused about `NSArray` initialization. The confusing thing is we have different `init` methods to init it, and if I just init it without giving any size and any objects, how compiler knows it object count or size in `RAM`.
What's the logic/difference behind init method? Can anybody explain it briefly?

Edit:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]   initWithKey:@"quota" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
//How is that possible to modifying to immutable object
sortedArray = [sortedContainers sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

I know the differences between **NSArray** and **NSMutableArray** and I'm not looking for the differences. I just wonder how that code can compile/execute without an error.

Comment: Method `init` came from `NSObject`. For `NSArray` it's totally useless.

Comment: so there is no purpose or benefit using init?

Comment: @Cy-4AH It's not useless at all. It's just empty. An empty array is a fairly normal thing to return.

Comment: @RobNapier, you can return `@[]` if you need empty erray.

Comment: @Cy-4AH In very modern ObjC, yes. But that's just syntactic sugar and is quite new in any case. Before array literals were added, `[[NSArray alloc] init]` and `[NSArray array]` were pretty common. That said, in the example above, it is incorrectly used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[[NSArray alloc] init]` returns an empty, immutable array. There's nothing surprising about that. What else would you return from a method to mean "no items?"

> how compiler knows it object count or size in RAM

The object count is 0. It's empty. Its size in RAM is the size of an empty `NSArray`. `NSArray` is an object, so it has some standard `objc_object` overhead, plus some instance variables for `NSArray`.

That said, as an implementation detail, Cocoa optimizes this out and always returns the same singleton for all empty `NSArray` objects. You can demonstrate this with:

```
NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSArray *b = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%p", a);
NSLog(@"%p", b);
if (a == b) { // Pointer equality, not isEqual:
    NSLog(@"Same object");
}
```

---

So, what is this doing?

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // (1)
// ... code that doesn't matter ...
sortedArray = [sortedContainers sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]; // (2)
```

At line 1, you're creating a local pointer variable, `sortedArray` and pointing it to an empty array (it happens to be a singleton, but that's an optimization detail).

At line 2, you create a completely different `NSArray` by calling `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`. You then point `sortedArray` at that object. ARC sees that you're no longer pointing at the empty array, and releases it. (Again, optimization details jump in here and the actual steps may be different, but the effect will be the same.)

The correct code here would be:

```
// ... Code that sets up sortDescriptors ...
NSArray *sortedArray = [sortedContainers sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

---

Now, in very modern ObjC, you won't see `[[NSArray alloc] init]` written out very often. It's easier to write `@[]` (which is really just syntactic sugar for a method call). But before array literals were added to language, `[[NSArray alloc] init]` or `[NSArray array]` were reasonably common.

Comment: so how this code executed without an error. `NSArray *sortedArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"quota" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
    sortedArray = [sortedContainers sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]; `

Comment: with no size how could it returns an array?

Comment: Your code is creating and throwing away an empty array; I'm not sure why you're doing that. You probably want to make more clear your confusion in the question rather than in comments.

Comment: I think I get the idea behind it. This code firstly allocate an empty array and then other line changes its pointer with and non-empty array is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If you just init `NSArray` without giving any size and any objects it will remain empty during lifetime. `NSArray` is immutable

If your question is about `NSMutableArray`, read [here at the SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591296/what-is-the-data-structure-behind-nsmutablearray)

Comment: I know it's immutable so what can be the purpose to init it? Why or when do we need it?

Comment: There are useful `-arrayByAddingObject:(id)anObject` and `-arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:` methods to get new `NSArray` from existing one